# Postgre SQL incorrect syntaxt near If

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2, rails-postgresql

I'm trying to create function but it's having error at If statement don't know what's the problem with it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION uspgetcountrylistwithpagenumber(IN "PageNumber" integer, IN "PageSize"         integer, IN "WhereClause" text, IN "OrderBy" text) RETURNS SETOF getcountrylistitem AS
$BODY$declare 
RowData "getcountrylistitem"%rowtype;

    IF $1 <> -1 and $2 <> -1  then
        for RowData in
        loop
            execute 'Select "CountryId","CountryName"' ||
                    'from "MasterCountry"' ||
                    $3 || 
                    $4 ||
                    'limit' || $2 ||
                    'offset' || ($1-1)*$2           
            RETURN NEXT RowData;
        END LOOP;
        RETURN;     
    else
        for RowData in
        loop
            execute 'Select "CountryId","CountryName"' ||
                    'from "MasterCountry"' ||
                    'order by "CountryName" asc'
            RETURN NEXT RowData;
            END LOOP;
            RETURN;
    end IF;
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
ALTER FUNCTION public.uspgetcountrylistwithpagenumber(IN integer, IN integer, IN text, IN text)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

What i want to achieve is custom paging ..
I want to have a function that can take PageNumber,PageSize,WhereClause,and OrderByClause

```
PageNumber=1
PageSize=10
WhereClause=Where 1=1 and CountryName='INDIA'
OrderByClause=order by CountryName desc
```

above are the parameter values that can be helpful for solving my problem
Let me know if more information is required. Thank you in advance..:P

Comment: I don't see a `begin` to mark the beginning of the function's body.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `BEGIN` before the first `IF`.